# Java Synchronized List - Single thread iteration

Tags: java

I am using `Collections.synchronizedList`, I have multiple threads building this list. However after it's built I only have a single thread iterating through it. Is the below still imperative in this case?

> It is imperative that the user manually synchronize on the returned
>   list when iterating over it:
>
> ```
>     List list = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList());
>     ...   
>     synchronized (list) {
>       Iterator i = list.iterator(); // Must be in synchronized block
>       while (i.hasNext())
>           foo(i.next());
>     }
> ```

Comment: if all the threads are finished building your list, why you need concurrency control for single thread accessing it?

Comment: No. As extra integrity check / measure, you might wrap it in a `Collections.unmodifiableList`, Or for a speedup copy the data to a new list (does not relate to your concern).

Comment: That's pretty much my point, was just confirming my suspicions

Comment: If you can ensure single threaded access to the list after it is build, then can't see why iterating without synchronisation would be a problem. Iterator provides direct access to the backing list, just ensure it's not misused

Comment: The warning just says that the _structure_ cannot really deal with an iterator on a change by another thread: the state of the local iterator is not updated.

Answer (score 1):

After the list is built, and you are certain it no longer needs to be synchronized, create a new `unsynchronized` list from the old one. No need to continue paying the performance hit.

```
List< Whatever > list = new ArrayList<>( mySynchList ) ;
```

If the list will no longer need elements added or dropped or replaced, make it unmodifiable.

```
List< Whatever > list = 
        Collections.unmodifiableList ( 
            new ArrayList<>( mySynchList ) 
        ) 
;
```